# Prevent use of spacebar when input field is empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, input

I am making a chat application and i saw that whatsapp doesn't allow the use of space bar when there is no input yet, i did try to find it out in **stack overflow** itself but they gave the answer which worked only there, but when i tried in my react-app it showed this error:
`Unexpected use of 'event'  no-restricted-globals`
I am confused what to do, i got this at the first time:

[image: screen shot of the depreciated warning]

Then i went to the file and tried commenting the line(not sure if can),
but that too didn't work for me.
Like is there any other way i can achieve the same functionality without the use event

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: `
    function keyhandler(e) { 
        var e = window.event || e;
        var key = e.keyCode;
        //space pressed
        if (key == 32) { //space
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
`

Comment: You shouldn't have to do the `var e = window.event` stuff, just use it as-is.

Comment: @GayatriDipali `keydown={e => keyhandler(e)}` try using this way.

Comment: The thing as @tadman said i shouldn't call the function there anyways thanks

Comment: @Jai That's just an empty wrapper that doesn't really solve the problem so much as introduces extra syntax that's not necessary. That approach is useful *if* you need to switch up the arguments before calling, but `x => f(x)` is almost always pointless in that context where `f` does the job.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I have not seen the comment by OP. Agreed on calling of that function is not required but a reference to the function is enough as event is already in the arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `keyhandler` defined as? You should define it as `function keyhandler(event)` but inline it as `onKeyDown={keyhandler}` with *no arguments*.

You want to pass in a *function to be called*, not a *specific function call*. These are two different things.

The error indicates that `event` isn't what you think it is, that's resolved to `window.event`, it doesn't exist like you think it does, because that is now a function call with a static argument instead of the actual event that happened.